# How do I extract the process ID from Valgrind's output using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file with the output of a valgrind run. I need to print the number that valgrind shows every line (right after the "==").

But I need to do it in only one line and without using the ";".

I tried using the `head -1`, which gives me the first line and I know what I'm looking for is in it, then I was thinking about using `cut -d= -f3`, which I know, when using it on the file will give me what I want, but it outputs it several times and I want it once.

How can I combine them. or is it not the way to do it?

sample valgrind output:

```
==29192== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==29192== Copyright (C) 2002-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29192== Using LibVEX rev 1575, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==29192== Copyright (C) 2004-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==29192== Using valgrind-3.1.1, a dynamic binary instrumentati
```

and I want it to print only 29192 for the above example.

Comment: please update your question to include sample valgrind output AND what you want it to look like in the end. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `head -1` and `cut -d= -f3` with a pipe: `head -1 file | cut -d= -f3`

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
sed -e 's/==\(.*\)==.*/\1/'
```

You might want to pass it through `| uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

**AWK Solution:**

```
awk -F"==" '{ print $2 }' INPUT_FILE | uniq
```

- Setting the Field Separator to `==`
- Printing Column #2
- Piping it to `uniq` to get distinct values.